# Python: Random combination from two files

Tags: python

New to python, bear with me. I have two text files, each has a word on a line (some funny words). I want to create a third file which has the random combination of those. with a space between them.

Example:

```
File1:
Smile
Sad
Noob
Happy
...

File2:
Face
Apple
Orange
...

File3:
Smile Orange
Sad Apple
Noob Face
.....
```

How can I Python this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from __future__ import with_statement
import random
import os

with open('File1', 'r') as f1:
    beginnings = [word.rstrip() for word in f1]

with open('File2', 'r') as f2:
    endings = [word.rstrip() for word in f2]

with open('File3', 'w') as f3:
    for beginning in beginnings:
        f3.write('%s %s' % (beginning, random.choice(endings)))
        f3.write(os.linesep)
```

Comment: Percent.py:5: Warning: 'with' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6
  File "Percent.py", line 5
    with open('tt', 'r') as f1
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Points for using os.linesep. Why not just use readlines rather than the list comprehensions?

Comment: @johnshaddad  2 reasons it didn't work for you.  1) I accidentally left the colons off of the end of the with statments.  That's now fixed.  2) You are using python 2.5 so you need to add `from future import with_statement` to the top of the file.

Comment: could you modify your post to include the "from future import with_statement".. I am trying it it is still not working..

Comment: @Zack Bloom  I used the list comp to remove the line endings which `readlines` preserves.

Comment: Your right, for some reason I thought readlines behaves differently.

Comment: Thanks everyone, this worked on my version of Python as required!

Answer (score 1):

Start by parsing the input files, so you end up with a list of two lists, each containing the words in one if the files.  We will also use the shuffle method in the random module to randomize them:

```
from random import shuffle

words = []
for filename in ['File1', 'File2']:
  with open(filename, 'r') as file: 
    # Opening the file using the with statement will ensure that it is properly
    # closed when your done.

    words.append((line.strip() for line in file.readlines()))
    # The readlines method returns a list of the lines in the file

    shuffle(words[-1])
    # Shuffle will randomize them
    # The -1 index refers to the last item (the one we just added)
```

Next we have to write our list of output words to a file:

```
with open('File3', 'w') as out_file:
  for pair in zip(words):
    # The zip method will take one element from each list and pair them up

    out_file.write(" ".join(pair) + "\n")
    # The join method will take the pair of words and return them as a string, 
    # separated by a space.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random    
list1 = [ x.strip() for x in open('file1.txt', 'r').readlines()]
list2 = [ x.strip() for x in open('file2.txt', 'r').readlines()]
random.shuffle(list1)
random.shuffle(list2)
for word1, word2 in zip(list1, list2):
    print word1, word2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
file1 = []
for line in open("file1.txt"):
    file1.append(line)
#or just list(open("file1.txt"))
...
file3 = open('file3.txt','w')
file3.write(...)
```

and work off that. Look at the `random` module and its functions. (http://docs.python.org/library/random.html)

If you are new to Python, look at a tutorial like Dive into Python (http://diveintopython3.ep.io/), available online.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like

```
f = open(file,'r')
data = [" "]

while data[-1] != "":
    data += [f.readline()
# do this a second time for the second file
```

and then

```
out = ""
from random import randint
for x in xrange(len(data)):
     y = randint(0, len(data) -1)
     if data[y] != 0: 
        out += data[y] + "\n"
        data[y] = 0

f3 = open(third file,'w+b')
f3.write(out)
```

this is a terrible code, but it should work

Answer (score 0):

this is a quick try...

```
import random

f1 = [line.rstrip() for line in open('file1', 'r').readlines()]
f2 = [line.rstrip() for line in open('file2', 'r').readlines()]

random.shuffle(f1)
random.shuffle(f2)
out = zip(f1, f2)

f3 = open('file3', 'w')
for k, v in out:
    f3.write(k + ' ' + v + '\n')
```